# A function to fit a random forest model and return the results of specified data

Tags: r, function, functional-programming, random-forest, r-caret

consider the following data frame:

```r
dat1 <- data.frame(Loc = rep(c("NY","MA","FL","GA"), each = 1000),
                   Region = rep(c("a","b","c","d"),each = 1000),
                   ID = rep(c(1:10), each=200),
                   var1 = rnorm(1000),
                   var2=rnorm(1000),
                   var3=rnorm(1000))
```

`Loc` and `Region` are two grouping variables for `ID`. Assume I have several other data frames like `dat1`. I am trying to write a function that will automatically fit a random forest model to the data. I want to specify the dataframe, grouping variable, and columns that I want it to use. 
I have tried variants of the following functions, but keep getting error messages that say `Error in get(dat, envir = .GlobalEnv) : invalid first argument` when I try to run them

```r
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
rand.f <- function(dat,groupvar,cols){
  model <- train(groupvar ~ paste0(cols,collapse = "+"), data = dat, method = "rf", trControl = trainControl("cv", number = 10), importance = T)
  c.e <- model$finalModel$confusion[, "class.error"]
  print(c.e)
}
rand.f(dat="dat1", groupvar = "Region", cols = 5:6)
  model$bestTune 
##################
rand.f <- function(dat,groupvar,cols){
  model <- train(get(dat, envir=.GlobalEnv)[,groupvar] ~ paste0(cols,collapse = "+"), data = dat, method = "rf", trControl = trainControl("cv", number = 10), importance = T)
  c.e <- model$finalModel$confusion[, "class.error"]
  print(c.e)
}
rand.f(dat="dat1", groupvar = "Region", cols = 5:6)
  model$bestTune
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The way you are creating / using the formula is flawed. Just look at what happens when you execute e.g. `groupvar ~ paste0(cols,collapse = "+")`

Comment: @coffeinjunky I see, so is there a way to specify those terms inside the `train()` call (as I tried to do) or is it better to create new (temporary) objects within the function that get and hold the specified data from your environment, and give those to the `train()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should be working:

```
rand.f <- function(dat,outcome){
  model <- train(x = dat[, cols, drop=F]
                 , y = dat[, outcome]
                 , method = "rf"
                 , trControl = trainControl("cv", number = 2)
                 , importance = T)

  c.e <- model$finalModel$confusion[, "class.error"]

  return(c.e)
}
```

which also works for numbers as well as vectors for the column names, e.g.

```
cols <- colnames(dat1)[5:6]
```

Note that I renamed the 'grouping' variable as it is a bit unclear what the grouping variable should be in this context. I have renamed it as outcome that is to be predicted to highlight what this stands for. If you did indeed try to predict the region, you can ignore this comment.

If you do want to trigger this function for different groups in your data, i.e. separate forests for different subsets, then you would best do that outside of this function.

Comment: this does work, thanks. I am confused about when I have to specify paste or print for objects within a function, and for example when you run this function, why you have to place quotations around the name of the `outcome` but not the name of the `dat`. would this change if you specified something within the function using `paste`? could you attempt to clarify this? maybe I should open a new question on the site for this

Comment: You only specify `print` if you want to print out something to the console, like a message or so. You specify `return` to explicitly return something after the function call. If you call the function, `outcome` will be a string, such as `"var1"`, so you are actually using a string in e.g. `dat[, outcome]`, which will be read as `dat[, "var1"]`. There is a whole book to be written about standard evaluation and non-standard evaluation. If you use packages from the `tidyverse`, you are likely going to encounter non-standard evaluation, where you don't use quotes. Let's say it's complicated.

Comment: And `paste`, you use to concatenate strings. Regarding `dat1`, this is an object already in the environment. I am passing the whole object, not just the name, hence no quotation needed.